# Bluemix port binding

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

[Official instructions](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Containers/index.html#container) state the following:

> ```
>     ice ip bind <Address> <Your_Container>
>
>     where <Address> is the returned IP address.
> ```
>
> Your application is set up and ready to use. If you used ibmliberty as
>   your base image in the Dockerfile, as in the previous example, you can
>   access your running IBM WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Profile
>   server by pointing your web browser to: http://:9080/

I got the list of my IPs using "sudo ice ip list".
Then I tried to bind the IP using three different commands:

```
user@comp:~$ sudo ice bind http://$ip/ $containerId
user@comp:~$ sudo ice ip bind http://$ip:$port $containerId
user@comp:~$ sudo ice ip bind http://$ip:$port $containerName
```

But got the same error message:

```
Target is container cloud. Invoking cloud service...
usage: ice [-h] [--verbose] [--cloud | --local]
           {login,tlogin,ps,run,inspect,logs,start,stop,restart,pause,unpause,rm,images,search,info,ip,help}
           ...
ice: error: argument subparser_name: invalid choice: 'bind' (choose from 'login', 'tlogin', 'ps', 'run', 'inspect', 'logs', 'start', 'stop', 'restart', 'pause', 'unpause', 'rm', 'images', 'search', 'info', 'ip', 'help')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bind succesfully using following command syntax

```
sudo ice ip bind $ip $containerName
```

Contrary to official instructions the `ip bind` command does not like "http://" and ":port" arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that.  The team is working on getting the docs updated.  Thanks for finding this!