# Deploying spark-jobserver to BlueMix Spark Node

Tags: apache-spark, docker, ibm-cloud, spark-jobserver

I'm trying to deploy and connect instance of `spark-jobserver` in a docker container to BlueMix Spark service. Locally, container start perfectly with a command `docker -d -p 8090:8090 {image-name}`, but it looks like BlueMix `ice -p` command works differently and only allows to specify BlueMix port. How do I make this container available from BlueMix?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/28201033/6309 help?

Comment: Thanks, But that look like not the what I needed. Public IP binding is working for me, app is just not answering on requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running the `ice` command line interface correctly and also binding a public IP address as you mentioned in you comments above.

The problem is that port 8090 is not currently exposed in the IBM Containers firewall. For security reasons there is a limited number of ports exposed.

You can try to use another port (like for example 9080) or your can open a support ticket in the web site below and request port 8090 to be added to the firewall whitelist:

http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport